# Test async onload handler with Mocha/Chai/Sinon

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to add a test for a function that should be called after `image.onload`.
I'm attaching the handler in the `RenderObject` constructor which sets all the dimensions for objects with that image source on load.
The code works as expected when I run it but I fail to create a test that succesfully proves this.

```
import { assert, expect } from "chai";
import "mocha";
import * as Sinon from "sinon";
import { IRenderObect } from "../interfaces/IRenderObject";
import { Point } from "./Point";
import { RenderObject } from "./RenderObject";

const imageSrc = "../../images/test80x100.png";
const initialPosition = new Point(10, 20);
const objectList = RenderObject.getObjectList();

afterEach(done => {
  objectList.forEach(o => o.destroy());
  done();
});

describe("RenderObject", () => {
  it("When a new image is loaded setDimensionsForImage is called", () => {
    const spy = Sinon.spy(RenderObject.setDimensionsForImage);
    const renderObject = { imageSrc: "xxx", initialPosition };
    const object = new RenderObject(renderObject);

    assert.ok(spy.calledOnce); // Fails as it should be async
  });

  it("Object has correct dimensions for image", done => {
    const spy = Sinon.spy(RenderObject.setDimensionsForImage);
    const renderObject = { imageSrc, initialPosition };
    const object = new RenderObject(renderObject);

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        expect(object.width).to.equal(80); // Also fails...
        expect(object.height).to.equal(100);
      } finally {
        done();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });

  it("Add new objects to the object list", () => {
    const renderObject = { imageSrc, initialPosition };
    const object = new RenderObject(renderObject);

    expect(objectList.length).to.equal(1);
  });

  it("Remove objects from the object list once destroyed", () => {
    const renderObject = { imageSrc, initialPosition };
    const object = new RenderObject(renderObject);
    object.destroy();

    expect(objectList.length).to.equal(0);
  });
});
```

How can I test that dimensions are correctly applied after image load?

**edit:**
I think my test setup can't load images. I guess I need to set use Chrome headless...

Comment: Don't you have some events that can be handled so you do not have to guess with `setTimeout`?

Comment: @H.B. I just logged calls to the constructor and setDimensionsForImage. The second is never called so I think the problem is in my test environment. Guess I'll have to setup Chrome headless as environment first.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, `setTimeout` is not a member of the window object and inside of the arrow function, the object passed to the describe callback is `this`. Didn't you get an error? 
You could try using it so,

```
it("Object has correct dimensions for image", done => {

}).timeout(()=>{

}, 1000)
```

Comment: setTimeout is a property of window, but I don't want it. I want to test the Image.onload handler

Comment: Can you post the renderobject code? As your test exists, you are simply invoking the constructor     const object = new RenderObject(renderObject);
 which obviously could not be calling any method from within it so the spy.calledonce test will never pass unless the getobjectlist method is calling the setDimensionsForImage() method.
sinon.spy requires the first parameter as the module/object and the second the method name to spy on, as string. So, if you post the code, I could test it.